# Different image width on a node and on block

Tags: 8, media

I noticed that there are differences in the way inline images are displayed when added to 'Body' of the 'Basic Page' and 'Body' of a 'Basic block'. In the first case the image is internally scaled down to match the width of the container (added attribute 'width=909' [screenshot 1]) whilst in the second case the image spills out over the element [screenshot 2]

[image: Basic page body image]

[image: Basic block body image]

I looked at image styles and field display options but couldn't figure out what is causing this behaviour. I'd like to preserve the scaling of the 'Basic Page' for the blocks. Has anyone else come across this issue? I'm running Drupal 8.1.9.

EDIT 1:
 @Smalution I checked the region width, too. Both 'region-content' and my custom region are 940px wide (descendants of 'col-sm-12')

Comment: Have you checked the region width as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can always make the image fit the container with CSS.

For example:

```
.block .content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you're using Bootstrap, you can achieve the same effect by adding the class `img-responsive` to the image.